# How would I use Regex to get a certain string out of this?

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am using webrequest to download a source from a page and then I need to use Regex to grab the string and store it in a string:

```
U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..
```

also need:

```
bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1
```

Both out of:

```
<td style="cursor:pointer;" class="" onclick="NewWindow('U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..', 'bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1', 'bpvstage_edit', '1200', '800')" onmouseout="HideHover();"><img src="gfx/info.gif" alt="" tipwidth="450" ajaxtip="openajax.php?target=modules/bpv/bpvstage_hover_info.php&rid=&oid=&bpvsid=&bpvname=" /></td>
```

It keep giving me errors like not enough )'s?

Thanks in advance.

Current code, probably wrong in every way. Really new to this:

```
 Regex rx = new Regex("(?<=class=\"\" onclick=\"NewWindow(').*(?=')");
            longId = (rx.Match(textBox2.Text).Value);
            textBox1.Text = longId;
```

Comment: What's giving you errors?

Comment: What regex do you have at the moment?

Comment: Share the code you have at the moment with us, please.

Comment: would give us the error you are getting

Comment: [Regex references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx). Unless you've tried something and put some work, why should we?

Comment: I have this at the moment, no idea what I am doing with Regex. Really new to it.  Code:

Comment: Regex rx = new Regex("(?<=class=\"\" onclick=\"NewWindow(').*(?=')");
            longId = (rx.Match(textBox2.Text).Value);
            textBox1.Text = longId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"onclick=""NewWindow\('([^']*)',\s*'([^']*)',.*");
if (match.Success)
{
    string longId = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string other = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

That will give you two groups with values:

```
U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..
bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I forgot to add that I am grabbing a WHOLE source. It has tons of NewWindow, OnClick etc. So it has to use the whole string since thats the only unique 'part' of the source code to split that from the rest of the source.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `NewWindow\('([^']*)', '([^']*)` will match what you require. The two strings required will be in Groups[1] and Groups[2].

```
var match = Regex.Match(textBox2.Text, "NewWindow\('([^']*)', '([^']*)");
var id1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
var id2 = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could also use simply string functions instead of a regex:

```
var s = "<td style=\"cursor:pointer;\" class=\"\" onclick=\"NewWindow('U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..', 'bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1', 'bpvstage_edit', '1200', '800')\" onmouseout=\"HideHover();\"><img src=\"gfx/info.gif\" alt=\"\" tipwidth=\"450\" ajaxtip=\"openajax.php?target=modules/bpv/bpvstage_hover_info.php&rid=&oid=&bpvsid=&bpvname=\" /></td>";
var tmp = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("NewWindow('")).Split('\'');
var value1 = tmp[1]; // U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..
var value2 = tmp[3]; // bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse HTML, then this non-regex approach works:

```
string html = // get your html ...
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();  
doc.LoadHtml(html);  // doc.Load can also consume a response-stream directly
var result = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
var firstTD = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td").FirstOrDefault();
if (firstTD != null)
{
    if (firstTD.Attributes.Contains("onclick"))
    {
        string onclick = firstTD.Attributes["onclick"].Value;
        int newWindowIndex = onclick.IndexOf("newWindow(", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (newWindowIndex >= 0)
        {
            string functionBody = onclick.Substring(newWindowIndex + "newWindow(".Length);
            string[] tokens = functionBody.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            result = tokens.Take(2).Select(s => s.Trim(' ', '\''));
        }
    }
}
```